# ¿Cómo leer respuesta de un modem GPRS? c# winForms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, serialport

mi problema es que estoy conectandome a un modem GPRS para mandar sms masivos. Sé que el GPRS devuelve algo (creo que es "OK") cuando envía un mensaje pero no logro dar con ello. Mi intención es pintar de verde la casilla de cada teléfono cuando se envíe el mensaje (al leer el "OK"), uno por uno. Pero no lo consigo, los pinta todos a al vez.
Los sms se envían todos sin ningún problema pero quiero que haga el bucle en el primer teléfono, pinte de verde cuando se envie y pase a hacer lo mismo en el siguiente teléfono.
Adjunto parte de mi código:

```
        public string spReadMsg { get; set; }
        public DateTime executionTime { get; set; }

        private void DataRecievedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

                spReadMsg = indata;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        } 
 private void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
                sp.PortName = "COM1";
                sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataRecievedHandler);
                sp.Open();
                spReadMsg = "+CMGS:";
                executionTime = DateTime.Now;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvClientes in dgvClientes.Rows)
                {


                    var telefono = dgvClientes.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + telefono + "\"" + Environment.NewLine); //CMSS?
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    sp.WriteLine(txtMensaje.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    sp.Write(new byte[] { 26 }, 0, 1);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    spReadMsg = ""; 
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(spReadMsg) && spReadMsg.Contains("+CMGS:"))
                        {
                            dgvClientes.Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (DateTime.Now > executionTime.AddSeconds(30))
                        {
                            dgvClientes.Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tiene foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvClientes in dgvClientes.Rows).  Probablemente sería mejor si tiene foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvCliente in dgvClientes.Rows) para que no cause confusión.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo es que la variable `spReadMsg` no se está limpiando una vez dentro del if, con lo cual la primera vez que se asigne un valor quedará ese valor siempre.
Trata se inicializarla al principio del bucle for `spReadMsg = "";`